# How do I hide and unhide specific text in a batch file?

Tags: scripting, batch-file, cmd, hide, show

I'm making a small, survival-based game.

Now what I want to know is how can I hide specific text from showing.

Here's an example.

```
echo Character:
echo.
echo Your hunger level is %hunger% out of 100.
```

If the variable hunger equals 90, I want to show: "You are starving" underneath, but when it's less I want it to not show at all.

How do I do this?

Comment: Excuse me. I encourage you to made clearer questions, for example: "How to display specific text conditionally?". Because "How to hide and unhide specific text?" means precisely that, and it can be done! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
SET VARIABLE=2
IF %VARIABLE%==1 echo "this should be shown if the variable is 1"
IF %VARIABLE% GTR 1 echo "this should be shown if the variable is less than 1"
IF %VARIABLE% LSS 1 echo "this should be shown if the variable is greater than 1"
```